# Add a space after 3 characters

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-progressbar

I have a seekbar which set values from 1500 to 48500 when on progress to an EditText. I want to add a space after ever 3 characters on progress changed for example 1500 becomes 1 500, 1 600, 30 000, 48 500. How can i achieve this. I mean formatting the progressed number so that after 3 characters it set a space.

Here is my working

```
decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0 000");

SeekBar mSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekvalue);

    mSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
       {

           progress = progress + 1500;

        edt_validate.setText(decimalFormat.format(Integer.toString(progress)));
         //edt_validate.setText(Integer.toString(progress + 1500));

       }

      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    });
```

Comment: check out [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: i want to set a space after every 3 digits e.g. 1500 to 1 500

Comment: and your problem is? in your question you say it is working

Comment: its ok Marco don't mind and thanks you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class. I don't get the actual regex to do it, so I did in this way (just be careful of `null` String) :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
edt_validate.setText(df.format(progress).replaceAll(",", " ")));
```

Comment: Yes null String will cause a force close

Answer (score 1):

I would use DecimalFormat. The following should do the trick:

```
int numberToFormat = 10000;
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance((Locale.getDefault()));
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
String formattedResult = formatter.format(numberToFormat).replaceAll(","," ");
```

This will give 10 000

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work using an homemade implementation. I did not test this since im not running eclipse on this computer so it might need some finetuning

```
String s ="1000";
String temp="";
if(s.length>=4){ // do nothing if length is less then 4
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
       if(i%3=0){ // every third char, add a space along with the value in s
          temp.charAt(i)=" "; //first add the space
          temp.charAt(i+1)=s.charAt(i); // then add the char at the next index
          }
       else
          temp=s.charAt(i); // If its not a "third char" just add it without the space

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer a bit late I know. But for the sake of people like me falling on this thread and wanting a cleaner way than using regex:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###");
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
```

You have to invoke `setDecimalFormatSymbols()` at the end because `getDecimalFormatSymbols()` clones the object used by `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: how to use it this.